# How to copy TortoiseGit settings from one computer to the other?

Tags: windows-7-x64, tortoisegit

I want to move my menu settings of TGit from one PC to other, but cant find them on HDD. Is it in registry somewhere? I'm on Windows 7 if that is important.

Comment: See [my article](http://www.marcoeckstein.com/it/how-to-share-tortoisegit-settings-between-multiple-machines/).

Comment: @MarcoEckstein Good points. I took the liberty to reference your article in my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last comment of [TortoiseGit Issue 1013](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1013) seems to show those entries are in:

```
HKCU/Software/TortoiseGit/
```

---

[Marco Eckstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443836/marco-eckstein) points out however in [his article](http://www.marcoeckstein.com/it/how-to-share-tortoisegit-settings-between-multiple-machines/):

> - There are some values which should probably never be shared between different TortoiseGit installations, e.g. `CurrentVersion`.
> - There are some values which you may not want to share between installations, e.g. those beneath the subkey `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\TortoiseGit\History` if you have one installation at home and one at work.
> - Some values will only be created when you change the configuration to be different then the default.
>   E.g., a new installation will not have any values for context menu configuration. If you would use a `.reg` file on another new installation, that would not be a problem. But if the other installation would already have values for non-default configuration, you would not overwrite the non-default configuration with the default configuration by importing a `.reg` file.

His script [`Set-TortoiseGitSettings.ps1`](https://github.com/marco-eckstein/admin-tools/blob/d9763ddfe3db5b91490dc5cfedeeaf86afa5894d/windows/Set-TortoiseGitSettings.ps1) will help set the right configuration across workstation.